# Javascript setTimeout quirk?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, settimeout

I'm trying to implement a client-side autologout feature. The idea is that 30 seconds before your session expires, you receive a warning that lets you extend the session. Everything works great except...

I use two `setTimeout` calls in the `$(document).ready` function to set the warning timeout and to set the logout timeout. But the crazy thing is that the order in which I set the timeouts matters! If I set the logout timer first, only the warning timer fires. If I set the warning timer first and then the logout timer, then they both fire.

This works for both timers:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isAuthenticated = <%= HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated.ToString.ToLower() %>;
    if(isAuthenticated)
    {
        warningTimer = setTimeout('warnUserOfSessionTimeout()', intWarningMS);
        logoutTimer = setTimeout('logoutSession()', intTimeoutMS);
    }
});
```

This only works for the warning timer:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isAuthenticated = <%= HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated.ToString.ToLower() %>;
    if(isAuthenticated)
    {
        logoutTimer = setTimeout('logoutSession()', intTimeoutMS);
        warningTimer = setTimeout('warnUserOfSessionTimeout()', intWarningMS);
    }
});
```

Here is the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var intTimeoutMS = <%= FormsAuthTimeoutMinutes %> * 60 * 1000;
    var intCountDownSecs = 30;
    var intWarningMS = intTimeoutMS - intCountDownSecs * 1000;
    var logoutURL = "<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Logout.aspx") %>";
    var keepAliveURL = "<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/KeepAlive.aspx") %>"
    var logoutTimer;
    var warningTimer;
    var countDownClockTimer;
    var intClockSeconds = intCountDownSecs;

    function logoutSession() {
        window.location = logoutURL;
    }

    function warnUserOfSessionTimeout() {
        $("#sessionTimeout").dialog({
            title: 'Are you still there?',
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:false,
            show: { effect: "slide", direction: "up", duration: 400 },
            hide: { effect: "slide", direction: "up", duration: 500 },
            buttons: {
                "Keep Working": function () {

                    // Keep session alive on server
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: keepAliveURL,
                        cache: false
                    });

                    // Clear and reset timers
                    clearTimeout(logoutTimer);
                    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
                    clearInterval(countDownClockTimer);
                    logoutTimer = setTimeout('logoutSession()', intTimeoutMS);
                    warningTimer = setTimeout('warnUserOfSessionTimeout()', intWarningMS);

                    $("#sessionTimeout").dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }).dialog("open");

        // Reset and animate display clock
        intClockSeconds = intCountDownSecs;
        animateCountdownClock();
        countDownClockTimer = setInterval('animateCountdownClock()', 1000);
    }

    function animateCountdownClock() {


        var sec_num = parseInt(intClockSeconds, 10);
        var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0" + hours;}
        if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes;}
        if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds;}

        $('#countDown').text(minutes + ':' + seconds);

        if(intClockSeconds > 0)
        {
            intClockSeconds -= 1;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isAuthenticated = <%= HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated.ToString.ToLower() %>;
        if(isAuthenticated)
        {
            logoutTimer = setTimeout(logoutSession, intTimeoutMS);
            warningTimer = setTimeout(warnUserOfSessionTimeout, intWarningMS);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="sessionTimeout" style="display: none; z-index: 1001;">
    <p style="font-size: 13px;">
        It appears that your computer has been left unattended. As a security precaution,
        you are about to be automatically logged out.
        <br />
        <br />
        Do you want to keep working?
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>Time remaining:&nbsp;<span id="countDown"></span></strong>
        <br />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: First: You shouldn't pass strings to `setTimeout`. Just pass your functions directly: `setTimeout(warnUserOfSessionTimeout, intWarningMS);`. Also, do either of those functions clear any of the other timers?

Comment: Yes, the warning function can clear the other times, if the user clicks a button on the dialog box that the function pops up. The logout function just  changes the window location to the logout page.

Comment: *"The logout function just changes the window location to the logout page."* That will tear down the current page, including cancelling all of its timers. But the symptom you describe is sort of the opposite, you've said that it "only works for the warning timer" suggesting the logout timer doesn't work.

Comment: @MikeC I like your suggestion. But I removed the quotes and I can still reproduce the same issue...

Comment: The order in which you schedule timed callbacks does matter: They go in a list, and scheduling two `setTimeout`s with the same timer value will fire the first, then the second. You haven't given us enough code to explain what you're seeing, but apparently the first one that fires is doing something that prevents or cancels the second one.

Comment: @John The strings thing isn't supposed to fit it. It's just a best practice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've posted the full code.

Comment: @MikeC Please see the full code I've added.

Comment: It's not *the* bug, but *a* bug is that you're restarting an `interval` timer whenever you show the warning message. So if you show the warning message twice, you'll end up with two copies of that running.

Comment: You'll have to go through the [mcve] process of taking things away until either A) it works, or B) you have a minimal, complete, runnable example you can include in the question as a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button lets you do live, runnable examples in the question). I can't see any reason the order of those particular `setTimeout` calls would matter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The interval gets cleared if the user clicks the Keep Working button. `clearInterval(countDownClockTimer);`. Otherwise, they get logged out anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good suggestion the with the minimal example. It appears to be the animations in the jQuery dialog, believe it or not. If I strip it down everything in the `warnUserOfSessionTimeout` function, and just leave an empty jQuery UI dialog call, it still has the same issue. If I then just comment out the `show` and `hide` options on the dialog, the issue is gone...